# rails 3 cookies

Tags: cookies, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a simple app where users type in stuff in a text filed to get various results.  I would like a feature where if a user enters something and then closes the browser tab, the next time they come, I can show them their previous/recent searches.  This will persist even if they close the whole browser and open it again.

I believe this can be done by help of cookies.  Are there some good rails3 gems for using cookies or any simple tutorial that could guide me in a direction?

Answer (score 3):

[http://railstutorial.org/chapters/sign-in-sign-out#sec:remember_me](http://railstutorial.org/chapters/sign-in-sign-out#sec%3aremember_me)

This is a great book to get you started with rails3. (I would recommend to read it from the beginning)

In the link above, listing 9.12 gives you a good explanation about cookies.

Answer (score 0):

Store the info in the session object:

```
session[:user_entry] = the_user_entry
```

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#session

Comment: He asked for persistence, a session will not suffice in this case as it will be lost as soon as the browser is closed.